# gpg — decrypt only content directly to stdout

Tags: bash, gnupg

I have the file `secret.txt.gpg` which I would like to decrypt, such that the content is stored within a variable like that:

```
TXT=$(gpg --decrypt secret.txt.gpg)
```

But this way a lot of extra `gpg: …` lines are added, containing information about the key etc. like that:

```
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID xxxx, created xxxx
  "xx xx (xx) <xx@xx.xx>"
gpg: Signature made xxx
gpg:                using RSA key xxx
…
Secret Message
```

By the way:

```
gpg -d secret.txt.gpg > out.txt
```

is just writing the content into the file.

How can I capture the content only, without writing it to a file?

### Update

Even though @Roger's answer is better and explains the why, I could make it using this:

```
TXT=$(gpg --decrypt secret.txt.gpg > /dev/stdout)
```

Comment: Are the extra lines not in the file? The man page is clear enough for `--decrypt` : `Decrypt  the file given on the command line (or STDIN if no file is specified) and write
              it to STDOUT (or the file specified with --output)`

Comment: no they are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The GPG messages are written to STDERR, which is why piping STDOUT to a file omits those messages.

If the encrypted file is not signed you usually suppress the messages about encryption by providing the `--quiet` switch. If the file is signed you will still get messages about the signature. Even if you provide the `--skip-verify` you will still get a message gently informing you that signature verification was suppressed.

In order to suppress all those message I suggest you pipe STDERR to `/dev/null`, e.g.:

```
TXT=$(gpg --decrypt secret.txt.gpg 2>/dev/null)
```